# как снести Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, grub

Всем привет. Выделил место (локальный диск) для установки Ubuntu. Windows стоит на диске C а Ubuntu на диске E. Теперь хочу снести Ubuntu и оставить Windows. Мне только надо отформатировать диск E? Например через MiniTool Partition Wizard Professional?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Это зависит от того, чей загрузчик используется. Если Windows - то да, достаточно вынести том Убунты и удалить её из вариантов загрузки. Но если установлен начальный загрузчик Убунты, придётся сначала восстановить загрузчик Windows, и только потом грохать Убунту.

**UPD:** Для форматирования тома рекомендую использовать штатное средство форматирования ОС, а не сторонние программные продукты.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51302/discussion-on-answer-by-akina---ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

**Это ответ для случая установки второй винды вместо убунту.**

Можно просто начать ставить винду, а при установке выбрать раздел с убунтой и отформатировать. Если сейчас используется grub, то винда при установке сама его перезапишет собственным загрузчиком. В таком случае потом надо будет добавить имеющуюся винду (первую) в загрузчик второй. Вероятно, для этого подойдёт [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).